# How to Calculate the power consumtion on a network of idle and active devices (Simulation)?

Tags: mininet

Am doing a project on a way to calculate the power consumption on a network of routers and switches, what i want is when one or more device are idle so the power consumption will be less. i want to calculate the power consumption at that moment.
Am using mini net software to simulate this, i have created the network but i don't know how can i calculate the power or what to use to do that ?
how can i do this ? and is there a more suitable software that can accomplish this?

in the real world i could use a clamp meter and capture the the drawn current and the voltage and from the both i can obtain the power, but how can i simulate this?

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The power consumption of routers and switches is constant, whether they are switching packets or not.

Comment: Incorrect, there's a delta that can go up to 25%, for reference read https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-642-01399-7_62.pdf
Where does your information come from? What makes you sure you can give this information out as an answer? Check the guidelines for SO answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a similar project. My best reference for the moment is [this study](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-642-01399-7_62.pdf) but there's much more you can keep into account if you're reeeeally motivated. Should script it on your own though, I haven't found much in terms of a ready-made solution for this need.